# just a suggestion about links on this website

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Just a suggestion: it would be useful to have links to the gazebo web site and wiki on this web site as well.  Quite often I want to go to one of the other sites and I have to use my bookmarks.  This is not really much of a bother, but I thought it would be useful to have links between the sites.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/93/just-a-suggestion-about-links-on-this-website/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Good idea.  We've added links to the top left of the page.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0